# wake up a thread from its state using notify

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am desperate...I'm working all the day on a program but I didn't resolve my issue about thread cuncurrency.Please help me.

I have this class which is a generic Item.My problem is when this object enters in wait() it doesn't wake up anymore even if I call on the same object the method `putItemToWork()`.I would know if there is a mistake on the code about cuncurrency because really I don't understand where I make mistakes...

### Item Class

```
import java.io.*;

public class Item implements Serializable
{
private String id;
private String category;
private String machine;
private boolean isWorked;

private String mchTemp = null; 

public Item(String id,String category,String machine,boolean isWorked)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.category = category;
    this.machine = machine;
    this.isWorked = isWorked;
}

public synchronized void putItemToWork(String id_machine)
{    
    try
        {
            System.out.println("Working the item...");
            Thread.sleep((long)(1+Math.random()*10000));
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie) {ie.printStackTrace(); }

            mchTemp = id_machine;        
    isWorked = true;
    notify();
}

public synchronized String getWorkedItem()
{
    if(mchTemp == null)
    {
        try
        {   
            wait();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie) {ie.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    return mchTemp;
}

public String getId()
{
    return this.id;
}

public String getCategory()
{
    return this.category;
}

public String getMachine()
{
    return this.machine;
}

public boolean isWorked()
{
    return this.isWorked;
}
}
}
```

### ServerMultiThread

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ServerMultiThread implements Runnable
{   
Socket socket;
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private LinkedList<Item> itemsList;
private LinkedList<Machine> machinesList;
private static final boolean listening = true;
private JTextArea output;

public ServerMultiThread(LinkedList<Item> itemsList,LinkedList<Machine> machinesList,JTextArea output)
{
    this.itemsList = itemsList;
    this.machinesList = machinesList;

    this.output = output;

    try
    {
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8090);
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){ioe.printStackTrace(); }

    new Thread(this, "Server").start();
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    Item itemTemp = null;

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){@Override public void run(){output.append("Server in run!\n");}});

    while(listening)
    {

        try
        {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){output.append("Waiting for incoming connection...\n");}});

            socket = serverSocket.accept();

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){@Override public void run(){output.append("Connected to: "+socket.getInetAddress()+":"+socket.getPort()+"!\n");}});

            ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            synchronized(itemsList)
            {
                for(Item item : itemsList)
                {
                    if(!item.isWorked())
                    {
                        itemTemp = item;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                new ItemHandler(itemTemp,ous,output);
            }

        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
}
```

### ItemHandler

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ItemHandler implements Runnable
{
String id_machine;
private Item item;
private ObjectOutputStream ous;
//private ObjectInputStream ois;
private JTextArea output;

public ItemHandler(Item item,ObjectOutputStream ous,JTextArea output)
{
    this.item = item;
    this.ous = ous;
    //this.ois = ois;
    this.output = output;

    new Thread(this).start();
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        ous.writeObject(item);                    

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){output.append("Item Handler "+item.getId()+ " in run!\n");}});

        id_machine = item.getWorkedItem();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){public void run(){output.append("The item "+item.getId()+" was correctly worked by "+id_machine);}});

        //System.out.println("The item "+workedItem.getId()+" was correctly worked by "+workedItem.getMachine());
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){ioe.printStackTrace();}
}
}
```

### MachineApp

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MachineApp 
{
private Socket socket;
private String id_machine;

public MachineApp(String id_machine)
{
    this.id_machine = id_machine;

    try
    {
        this.socket = new Socket("localhost",8090);

        System.out.println("Estabilished connection to main server!");
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException uhe) {uhe.printStackTrace();}
    catch(IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace(); }

    execution();
}

private void execution()
{
    try
    {
        //ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());    
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());          

        Item item = (Item) ois.readObject();

        item.putItemToWork(id_machine);

        System.out.println("Item Worked!");
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {cnfe.printStackTrace(); }
    catch(IOException ioe) {ioe.printStackTrace(); }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MachineApp machineApp = new MachineApp(args[0]);        
}
}
```

Comment: how are you starting Threads? can you post the code for that as well?

Comment: What my code does is to take an object ITEM from the list, sent to MachineApp and wait a response.everything does in a thread ItemHandler that call wait()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me your code works just fine. Are you calling wait/notify from different threads:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Item item = new Item("id", "cat", "mach", false);

    Thread retrievalThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            item.getWorkedItem();
        }
    });

    Thread puttingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            item.putItemToWork("id");
        }
    });

    retrievalThread.start();
    puttingThread.start();
}
```

EDIT: after client code was added to question:
I could be wrong but you're sending item object via socket and then trying to call getWorkedItem on it. It doesn't work this way because once you've send item thru network object on the other side (even if it's happening in one JVM) that will be different object. Therefore calling notify on it won't trigger wake up from wait.

How to solve it? Well, you can add some kind of query interface to your server code so you could query which items were worked.

If it's no homework, or learning exercise I think that Hadoop can be good fit for your needs

Comment: Thanks @Petro Semeniuk. I finally understand the reason why nothing work and you saved me with those words: It doesn't work this way because once you've send item thru network object on the other side (even if it's happening in one JVM) that will be different object. Thanks now I understood

Comment: Well, you can add some kind of query interface to your server code so you could query which items were worked. Can you do an example? I don't know how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you're going to need to make `mchTemp` `volatile`, because you're writing to this field in one thread, and reading it from another. *Without* `volatile`, changes made in one thread may not be visible in another tread.

```
private volatile String mchTemp = null;
```

Comment: About using volatile --
http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/

Comment: mchTemp update happens only from synchronized block. Once wait is called monitor on this object will be released, also, the awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object (in this case after thread called notify _and_ exited synchronized block). So in this case volatile is not needed because visibility is guaranteed by object (Item itself) lock. Please correct me if I'm wrong